# How to remove these labels from my customized Google Chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Here's my screenshot of my customized Google Chart. I don't understand how to remove "My plot" legend and X-value (which is 30 now). Where can I controll it in Google Chart?

My code for the tooltip:

```
function info( index ) {
    return '<div style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;">Info:<br />' + index + '<br />' + chartData[ index + 1 ][ 1 ] + '</div>';
}
```

I add new column with that function to show my information:

```
//data <-- dataTable
data.addColumn( { 'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': { 'html': true } } );
for ( i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++ ) {
    data.setCell( i, 3, info( i ) );
}
```

There's no any legend info showing or index showing. It shows by itself :)

In the chart's options I have: `legend: { position: 'none' }`. My options are:

```
var chartOptions = {
    pointSize: 1,
    chartArea: { left: '7%', right: '0%', bottom: '12%', width: '100%', height: '100%' },
    legend: { position: 'none' },
    vAxis: { format: '#.#######' },
    colors: [ '#a52714', '#097138' ],
    crosshair: { color: '#666666', trigger: 'focus' },
    focusTarget: 'category',
    tooltip: { isHtml: true }
}
```

Screenshot is: [image: here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to chart options...

```
tooltip: {
  isHtml: true
}
```

also remove the following option...

```
focusTarget: 'category'
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I've updated my post above with the chart's options. I've already had that option :(

Comment: I use LineChart

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I thought I will never fix that problem.